# Identical answer posted long time after the first one. How to deal with it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355638/get-the-current-date-and-time#26787912) is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355638/get-the-current-date-and-time#21076228).

- No additional value added
- Posted long time after the first one

As such behaviour is not tolerable - how to deal with it?

- Only downvote?
- I want to flag it - can I do it and hope it would be removed? Which flag? For low quality?

I read some meta posts, but I cannot find an explicit answer fast, while the answer should be quite straightforward in this situation.

Also, there's a guy who noticed it, but no one took action.

Comment: You may use a custom flag, yes. That said, the question is abysmal from a research standpoint, and the plagiarized answer conforms to the now-usual `Try this one:-followed-by-code` standards, which makes it not unique at all, and therefore more susceptible to "maybe involuntary" plagiarism.

Comment: I agree that it's a "maybe involuntary" plagiarism. But IMO it still should be removed as it does not add additional value. I like reading more answers just for different approaches, and these things, even small, still eat some time and decrease quality. I'd like to help removing such things if I knew the correct approach.

Comment: I agree, that's why I cast a delete vote on that answer (and downvoted the question).

Comment: Thanks. So there's another option - to cast a delete vote - which I was not yet aware of. I'll wait for 3k rep impatiently just because of this tool :) Meanwhile, I downvoted the answer and raised a custom flag.

Comment: @TravisJ I read that post before posting my question. There is no explicit answer what to do in this straightforward situation. In that question, the discussion is about a case where 2 identical answers appeared in a time span of 9 seconds. However, I have a question where time span is 9 months. Within the question I noted this difference: "Posted long time after the first one".

Comment: @ZygD - The question doesn't mention the time frame though, only the main aspect of the answers being the same. While the first answer addresses the exact case, the second (still at +25) addresses the more general *For cases where one answer is significantly older, truly duplicate answers are not useful (because they don't add anything new and only clutter up the page) and do deserve downvotes* . I think you can see that happen here, as the answer was downvoted, and eventually deleted by Frederic, Deduplicator, and myself.

Comment: @TravisJ - I saw that line too. But it does not mention other options besides downvoting. So I asked about flagging and also found out about casting delete votes. The aim of this question was to find out what is the correct approach including every possibility, not only downvotes.

Comment: There's a massive elephant in this room, the question is *incredibly* trivial.  Out of 1000 .NET programmers, 999 know the answer.  And that's low-balling it.  Of course there will be a horse-shoe that wants to contribute as well without reading the other posts.  They'll keep coming.

Comment: @HansPassant - I understand that. Still, I think such things should be removed by some means. Just wanted to quickly find the answer which I failed. So I asked **a more structured direct question**. I am learning VB.NET at the moment (I'll learn other languages in the future too), so I google a lot and find these simple questions. At the same time, I want to contribute to the site. If this was the only case, I would not have asked. But I see such behaviour from time to time, so my question arose naturally, as I want the site not to be stocked with garbage, if I may say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `you > 3k rep` , you can also:

- cast a close vote

If `you < 3k rep` , options include:

- downvoting
- flagging - custom flag

Comment: I'm sure that privilige is at a much higher rep. [20K looks like it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @Deduplicator Yep. It seems like 3K is for close votes.

Comment: I just copied @ZygD answer as a gag ...

Comment: I didn't get the close vote part. If the question is reasonable and the first answer is too, and this isn't a dupe, why would you close the question?? The problem is with additional answer rather the question. I don't get it.